# Scooter start problem

Tags: starting

My scooter has run 7600 km and after a service 3 days ago it now stops while riding. I have had it stop in the middle of the road.

It is very difficult to then self start it.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Yes..three days ago

Comment: Did this only start after the service three days ago?

Comment: Yes ...they say everything is ok..but during ride its a problem

Comment: what kind of motor has it, carburated 4-stroke?

Comment: Yes it is..honda dio

Comment: Take it back to the place that did the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take it back to your shop and have them fix it.

Has probably something to do with the carburetor setting or the fuel-supply to it. Presumably they did work on it during service?

Comment: Does it have anything to do with spark plug?

Comment: Could also be, was work done on the spark plugs? If there is a loose connection the sparks may be insufficient to secure ignition ...

Answer (score 0):

If your scooter is provided with one, have the depression fuel tap and line checked.

Comment: What is a "depression fuel tap"? Are you referring to the choke?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what is the exact name. Maybe the "petcock"? Some scooters have the fuel line blocked unless the engine is running. Usually there are 2 tubes from the carburetor to the fuel tank. One is for fuel and one is for the depression which "switches the petcock on"

Comment: Hello...Yesterday my scooter was serviced and after 15km of its ride..it stooped...then I called the mechanic and we found out that he forgot to put the engine oil...so.after refilling the oil..the scooter is working.but I want to knw.m,whether thos will create some problems in the future or not?